# Why does php not push to firebase?

Tags: php, github, firebase

I am trying to connect php to firebase, here is my **index.php** code:

```
<?php
require_once('firebasephp/lib/firebaseInterface.php');
require_once('firebasephp/lib/firebaseStub.php');
require_once('firebasephp/firebaseLib.php');
require_once('fbasetokengenerator/FirebaseToken.php');
require_once('phpjwt/Authentication/JWT.php');

$firebase = new Firebase('https://shining-heat-3850.firebaseio.com/', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$data = [
'ip' => "123456789",
'session' => "1234",
'sequence' => "12",
'time' => "159159159",
'event' => "Pause",
'data' => "1" ];

$res = $firebase->push('https://shining-heat-3850.firebaseio.com/data.json', $data);
?>
```

Am I doing it right? I used [firebase-php by ktamas](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php), [firebasephp-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and firebase token generator. How can I connect to my firebase? It's just a simple push. By the way, I have not edited anything I used in require_once. The firebaseInterface.php, firebaseStub.php etc. are not edited and I just used it as is.

Comment: What does the error log indicate?

Comment: Well I'm using xampp. And again, the code above is my code for index.php. Whenever I run run this through a browser it shows nothing but a blank white page, I checked my firebase but there is no data there. So I was wondering if what I did was right.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend resetting your Firebase secret in the data dashboard - anyone viewing this post can access / edit any data / metadata about this Firebase and create authorized user tokens now that you've posted your secret

Comment: Also, what does your error log indicate? Find the correct one that displays PHP errors and add the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already connected to the database, when you are pushing data into a node, you don't need to specify full path there. Simply Use this syntax:

```
$res = $firebase->push('/', $data);
```

or

```
$res = $firebase->push('/node_name/subnode', $data);
```

Comment: This works wonders! But how do I do it if I want to get the data from firebase? Also can push be replaced by set and update?

Comment: Yes, you can see the full description with PHP examples here:
https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php#supported-commands

Comment: $firebase->set('/name/contact001', "John Doe");
$name = $firebase->get('/name/contact001');